# Writing an argument function in R

Tags: r, for-loop

[image: Writing a function]

My code works, but it seems that the iteration is not working. I am supposed to get MSE (50 times). Could someone check my code and see what is wrong with my iteration. Thank you.

My Solution :

```
arguments <- function(r,n,sig) 

{

#(a) Generate the data (X1i;X2i;X3i; Yi) from the following linear regression model:

x1i <- NULL
x2i <- NULL
x3i <- NULL
yi <- NULL
ei <- NULL

for (i in 1:r) {  # (d) Repeat (a) - (c) r times and save MSEj values for each 

coefficient.

  x1i <- runif(n)

  x2i<-runif(n)

  x3i<-runif(n)

  ei<-rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=sig^2)

  yi<- 1+3*x1i-1.5*x2i*x3i+ei 

  data<-cbind(x1i, x2i, x3i, yi)
  
  data

  data <- cbind.data.frame(x1i, x2i, x3i, yi)
  

#(b) Run regression analysis and save the estimated coefficients

regression <- lm(yi~x1i+x2i+x3i, data=data)
regression

my_estimates <- regression$coefficients

my_estimates

# (c) Calculate MSEj 

coefficients<-c(1,3,-1.5, 2)

names(coefficients) <- c('beta0', 'beta1' , 'beta2' , 'beta3')

MSE<-(my_estimates-coefficients)^2
names(MSE)<- c('MSE0', 'MSE1' , 'MSE2' , 'MSE3')
MSE

}

 return(rbind(MSE))
}

arguments(50,50,4)

# (e) Save the data set containing r values of MESj (j = 0; 1; 2; 3) in the file named mse.txt. 

write.table(rbind(MSE), file="MSE.txt", sep=" ", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote=F)
```

My code works, but it seems that the iteration is not working. I am supposed to get MSE (50 times). Could someone check my code and see what is wrong with my iteration. Thank you.

Comment: your question needs to be more focused. what specifically are you having trouble with can you pinpoint where you think things are going wrong?

Comment: The iteration is not working, I am supposed to get 50 MSE, but with the current code, I am only having one. So, I think my looping is not considered

Answer (score 0):

A few notes.

- `arguments` is a pretty terrible name for this function. It's not at all descriptive of what the function does. Maybe `lm_sim`?
- `x1i <- NULL` does nothing. You can delete all your `<- NULL` lines. This is only necessary if you want to jump right in to assigning to an index of `x1i`, e.g., `x1i[1] <- ...`. You're not doing that, so skip the `<- NULL`s.
- `data <- cbind.data.frame(x1i, x2i, x3i, yi)` is a long way of writing `data <- data.frame(x1i, x2i, x3i, yi)` (`cbind` is an often unnecessarily use function).
- Every time through the loop, you overwrite `MSE` with the the current values. Instead, you need to save each set of `MSE` values at a different index. Like this:

```
# before the loop initialize 
MSE <- matrix(NA, nrow = r, ncol = 4)
colnames(MSE) <- c('MSE0', 'MSE1' , 'MSE2' , 'MSE3')

# ...

# inside the loop
MSE[i, ] <- (my_estimates-coefficients)^2

# ...

# after the loop
return(MSE)
```

That will give you all the MSE estimates in a nice matrix, that you can then `write.table` on.

Putting it all together:

```
lm_sim <- function(r, n, sig) {
  
  MSE <- matrix(NA, nrow = r, ncol = 4)
  colnames(MSE) <- c('MSE0', 'MSE1' , 'MSE2' , 'MSE3')

  for (i in 1:r) {
    # (d) Repeat (a) - (c) r times and save MSEj values for each coefficient.
    #(a) Generate the data (X1i;X2i;X3i; Yi) from the following linear regression model:
    
    x1i <- runif(n)
    x2i <- runif(n)
    x3i <- runif(n)
    ei <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = sig ^ 2)

                       ## corrected formula typo here
                       ## needed "+ 2" 
    yi <- 1 + 3 * x1i - 1.5 * x2i + 2 * x3i + ei

    data <- data.frame(x1i, x2i, x3i, yi)
    
    #(b) Run regression analysis and save the estimated coefficients
    regression <- lm(yi ~ x1i + x2i + x3i, data = data)
    my_estimates <- regression$coefficients
    
    # (c) Calculate MSEj
    coefficients <- c(1, 3, -1.5, 2)
    MSE[i, ] <- (my_estimates - coefficients)^2
  }
  return(MSE)
}

lm_sim(5, 50, 4)
#              MSE0       MSE1        MSE2       MSE3
# [1,]   1.70991215 11.2100225   6.7951291  55.144162
# [2,]   0.04251383  9.8464094  15.0336459   5.560268
# [3,]  50.69016247 33.0424882   0.4345595  32.960442
# [4,] 126.22140452  0.3897318  21.1740809 225.536248
# [5,]   0.26383043  3.1635477 104.5239809  46.179812
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but I am having this error :           
Error in MSE[i, ] <- (my_estimates - coefficients)^2 : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but it seems the saving for MSE values is not working. I am having this error.  Error in MSE[i, ] <- (my_estimates - coefficients)^2 : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Comment: Added a working demo.

Comment: write.table(MSE, file="mse.txt", sep=" ", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote=F)                                                                      Do you have an idea on how to fix the saved data. When I saved it shows NA values in the file

Comment: I don't see any missing values. `results <- lm_sim(5, 50, 4)`. Check that `results` has no missing values: `anyNA(results)` gives `FALSE`. `write.table(results, file="mse.txt", sep=" ", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote=F)`. Opened the file and it looks fine. Reran the same code with `50` instead of `5`, all looks fine.